# Python Pandasでのデータ処理を簡潔に書きたい

Tags: python, pandas

## 困っていること

例のようなデータを入力としてもっています。
Pythonコードの中で、以下の "実現したい処理" を書きたいが、明らかに冗長な方法しか思いつきません。
どなたかスマートな書き方を思いつく方、お力を貸してください。

## 入力データ

"小分類ごとの数"と"中分類ごとの上限"が与えられている。

```
中分類 小分類 数量  中分類_上限
東北  青森  4   10
東北  岩手  5   10
東北  宮城  11  10
関東  東京  8   5
関東  千葉  3   5
近畿  大阪  6   3
近畿  京都  6   3
九州  福岡  0   2
九州  佐賀  0   2
```

## 実現したい処理

"小分類ごとの数"の合計を"中分類ごとの上限"に収めたい。

```
中分類 小分類 数量  中分類_上限  数量_変更後イメージ
東北  青森  4   10  2
東北  岩手  5   10  2
東北  宮城  11  10  6
関東  東京  8   5   4
関東  千葉  3   5   1
近畿  大阪  6   3   2
近畿  京都  6   3   1
九州  福岡  0   2   1
九州  佐賀  0   2   1
```

## 制約事項

・数は必ず0以上の整数にする
・割合はなるべく変わらないようにする
・余りは無いようにする

Comment: 念のため既存のコードも質問に含めた方がアドバイスが付きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 余りは無いようにする

この条件に関しては、かなり適当に調整しています(`idxmax` か `idxmin` に差分を加減)。

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)

data_csv = '''
中分類,小分類,数量,中分類_上限
東北,青森,4,10
東北,岩手,5,10
東北,宮城,11,10
関東,東京,8,5
関東,千葉,3,5
近畿,大阪,6,3
近畿,京都,6,3
九州,福岡,0,2
九州,佐賀,0,2
'''.strip()

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_csv))

def divide_with_keep_ratio(x):
  n = x['数量'].sum()
  if not n:
    x['数量'] = 1
    n = len(x)
  nums = np.round(x['中分類_上限']*x['数量']/n).astype(int)
  s, limit = nums.sum(), x['中分類_上限'].values[0]
  if s == limit: return nums
  if s > limit:
    nums[nums.idxmax()] -= (s - limit)
  else:
    nums[nums.idxmin()] += (limit - s)
  return nums

df['小分類ごとの数'] = (
  df.groupby('中分類', sort=False)
    .apply(divide_with_keep_ratio).values)

print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

| 中分類 | 小分類 | 数量 | 中分類_上限 | 小分類ごとの数 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 東北 | 青森 | 4 | 10 | 2 |
| 東北 | 岩手 | 5 | 10 | 2 |
| 東北 | 宮城 | 11 | 10 | 6 |
| 関東 | 東京 | 8 | 5 | 4 |
| 関東 | 千葉 | 3 | 5 | 1 |
| 近畿 | 大阪 | 6 | 3 | 1 |
| 近畿 | 京都 | 6 | 3 | 2 |
| 九州 | 福岡 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 九州 | 佐賀 | 0 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。
 s, limit = nums.sum(), x['中分類_上限'].values[0]
以下は全く思いつきませんでした。